# Convert Java Spark Dataframe into json value

Tags: java, json, apache-spark

I have a data frame that has 3 columns a, b, c.
I would like to have a JSON object that looks like this

```
{ 
     predictions : [
          {
               a:1,b:1,c:1
          },
          {
               a:2,b:2,c:3
          },...
    ]
}
```

where each row of the original data frame becomes a json object tucked into a high level object predictions.  Ideally I'd be able to partition each of these so that the length of the predictions list is no more than 100.  Does anyone have a clean way to do this?  I feel like I am missing something obvious

Answer (score 0):

Probably with a model like this:

```
public class Data {
    List<Dataframe> predictions;

    // ...
}

public class Dataframe {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    // ...
}
```

You can collect the data frames (up to 100) and then create JSON data with any library, like [Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial).

Comment: Would that not remove some of the performance benefits of using Spark Data Frames?  Would there be a way to do this with just spark without adding extra computation towards serialization and de serialization?